# Can't connect with my own Mumble Server

Tags: windows, mumble

I've got a problem with my connection to Mumble Server. The server is launched on 192.168.0.155, behind a router. On the router DMZ is enabled. Someone else is trying to connect on my public IP and the connection failed. What am I doing wrong? At the same time I'm able to successfully launch and connect TeamSpeak Server.

**Avast AV** - disabled

**Avast firewall** - disabled

**Windows firewall** - disabled

**Mumble Server on Windows:** Murmur 1.3.0 (1.3.0~499~g212e7c0~snapshot)

**Mumble Client on Windows:** Mumble 1.3.0 (1.3.0~499~g212e7c0~snapshot) 


**Router:** D-Link 524, DMZ enabled

Server log:

```
<W>2015-01-03 14:50:13.272 Initializing settings from D:/Dane SSD/mumble/murmur.ini (basepath D:/Dane SSD/mumble)
<W>2015-01-03 14:50:13.281 OpenSSL: OpenSSL 1.0.1j 15 Oct 2014
<W>2015-01-03 14:50:13.400 SSL: CA certificate filter applied. Filtered size: 698, original size: 698
<W>2015-01-03 14:50:13.401 ServerDB: Opened SQLite database D:/Dane SSD/mumble/murmur.sqlite
<W>2015-01-03 14:50:13.418 MurmurIce: Endpoint "tcp -h 192.168.0.155 -p 6502" running
<W>2015-01-03 14:50:13.418 Murmur 1.3.0 (1.3.0~499~g212e7c0~snapshot) running on Win: Windows 7 Home Premium Edition Service Pack 1 x64 - 6.1.7601: Booting servers
<W>2015-01-03 14:50:13.429 1 => Server listening on [::]:64738
<W>2015-01-03 14:50:13.434 1 => Server listening on 0.0.0.0:64738
<W>2015-01-03 14:50:13.437 1 => Failed to bind UDP Socket to 0.0.0.0:64738
<W>2015-01-03 14:50:13.457 Bonjour: Failed to load dnssd.dll
<W>2015-01-03 14:50:13.461 1 => Not registering server as public
<W>2015-01-03 14:50:17.325 1 => <1:(-1)> New connection: 127.0.0.1:58060
<W>2015-01-03 14:50:17.325 Connection: Failed to add flow to QOS
<W>2015-01-03 14:50:17.422 1 => <1:(-1)> Client version 1.3.0 (Win: 1.3.0~499~g212e7c0~snapshot)
<W>2015-01-03 14:50:17.426 1 => Starting voice thread
<W>2015-01-03 14:50:17.457 1 => CELT codec switch ffffffff80000010 0 (prefer ffffffff80000010) (Opus 1)
<W>2015-01-03 14:50:17.480 1 => <1:Krew(-1)> Authenticated
<W>2015-01-03 14:51:24.691 1 => <1:Krew(-1)> Connection closed: The remote host closed the connection [1]
<W>2015-01-03 14:51:24.702 1 => Ending voice thread
```

Client log:

```
[15:21:43] Connecting to server 78.88.XXX.XXX.
[15:22:13] Server connection failed: Connection timed out.
[15:22:23] Reconnecting.
[15:22:53] Server connection failed: Connection timed out.
```

Server host: netstat -a -n

```
  Protocol   Local adress          Destination adres             status

  TCP       0.0.0.0:135            0.0.0.0:0              NASťUCHIWANIE
  TCP       0.0.0.0:445            0.0.0.0:0              NASťUCHIWANIE
  TCP       0.0.0.0:554            0.0.0.0:0              NASťUCHIWANIE
  TCP       0.0.0.0:2869           0.0.0.0:0              NASťUCHIWANIE
  TCP       0.0.0.0:5357           0.0.0.0:0              NASťUCHIWANIE
  TCP       0.0.0.0:10011          0.0.0.0:0              NASťUCHIWANIE
  TCP       0.0.0.0:10243          0.0.0.0:0              NASťUCHIWANIE
  TCP       0.0.0.0:12025          0.0.0.0:0              NASťUCHIWANIE
  TCP       0.0.0.0:12110          0.0.0.0:0              NASťUCHIWANIE
  TCP       0.0.0.0:12119          0.0.0.0:0              NASťUCHIWANIE
  TCP       0.0.0.0:12143          0.0.0.0:0              NASťUCHIWANIE
  TCP       0.0.0.0:12465          0.0.0.0:0              NASťUCHIWANIE
  TCP       0.0.0.0:12563          0.0.0.0:0              NASťUCHIWANIE
  TCP       0.0.0.0:12993          0.0.0.0:0              NASťUCHIWANIE
  TCP       0.0.0.0:12995          0.0.0.0:0              NASťUCHIWANIE
  TCP       0.0.0.0:21320          0.0.0.0:0              NASťUCHIWANIE
  TCP       0.0.0.0:21321          0.0.0.0:0              NASťUCHIWANIE
  TCP       0.0.0.0:21332          0.0.0.0:0              NASťUCHIWANIE
  TCP       0.0.0.0:21333          0.0.0.0:0              NASťUCHIWANIE
  TCP       0.0.0.0:27275          0.0.0.0:0              NASťUCHIWANIE
  TCP       0.0.0.0:30033          0.0.0.0:0              NASťUCHIWANIE
  TCP       0.0.0.0:49152          0.0.0.0:0              NASťUCHIWANIE
  TCP       0.0.0.0:49153          0.0.0.0:0              NASťUCHIWANIE
  TCP       0.0.0.0:49154          0.0.0.0:0              NASťUCHIWANIE
  TCP       0.0.0.0:49159          0.0.0.0:0              NASťUCHIWANIE
  TCP       0.0.0.0:49194          0.0.0.0:0              NASťUCHIWANIE
  TCP       0.0.0.0:54535          0.0.0.0:0              NASťUCHIWANIE
  TCP       0.0.0.0:64738          0.0.0.0:0              NASťUCHIWANIE
  TCP       127.0.0.1:5939         0.0.0.0:0              NASťUCHIWANIE
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6502         0.0.0.0:0              NASťUCHIWANIE
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         0.0.0.0:0              NASťUCHIWANIE
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53049        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53052        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53054        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53055        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53057        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53059        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53061        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53064        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53067        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53068        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53073        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53074        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53075        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53080        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53081        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53084        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53086        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53089        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53090        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53091        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53092        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53093        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53095        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53097        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53100        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53101        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53102        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53103        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53106        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53112        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53113        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53114        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53117        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53118        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53119        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53120        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53122        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53123        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53125        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53126        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53128        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53130        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53131        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53132        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53134        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53135        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53137        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53139        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53141        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53143        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53144        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53146        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53148        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53149        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53151        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53154        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53155        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53156        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53157        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53158        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53159        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53160        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53161        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53162        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53163        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53164        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53165        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53166        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53168        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53170        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53171        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53172        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53173        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53174        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53175        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53176        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53177        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53178        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53180        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53181        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53183        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53184        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53186        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53188        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53189        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53190        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53191        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53193        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53194        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53196        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53197        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53198        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53199        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53200        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53201        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53203        USTANOWIONO
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53204        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53207        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53208        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53210        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53211        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53214        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:6881         127.0.0.1:53216        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:12025        0.0.0.0:0              NASťUCHIWANIE
  TCP       127.0.0.1:12110        0.0.0.0:0              NASťUCHIWANIE
  TCP       127.0.0.1:12119        0.0.0.0:0              NASťUCHIWANIE
  TCP       127.0.0.1:12143        0.0.0.0:0              NASťUCHIWANIE
  TCP       127.0.0.1:12465        0.0.0.0:0              NASťUCHIWANIE
  TCP       127.0.0.1:12563        0.0.0.0:0              NASťUCHIWANIE
  TCP       127.0.0.1:12993        0.0.0.0:0              NASťUCHIWANIE
  TCP       127.0.0.1:12995        0.0.0.0:0              NASťUCHIWANIE
  TCP       127.0.0.1:27275        0.0.0.0:0              NASťUCHIWANIE
  TCP       127.0.0.1:53053        127.0.0.1:21332        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:53056        127.0.0.1:21332        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:53060        127.0.0.1:21332        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:53062        127.0.0.1:21332        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:53063        127.0.0.1:6881         CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:53065        127.0.0.1:21332        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:53066        127.0.0.1:6881         CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:53068        127.0.0.1:6881         CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:53069        127.0.0.1:21332        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:53082        127.0.0.1:6881         CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:53085        127.0.0.1:6881         CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:53087        127.0.0.1:6881         CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:53088        127.0.0.1:6881         CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:53096        127.0.0.1:21332        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:53105        127.0.0.1:6881         CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:53116        127.0.0.1:6881         CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:53117        127.0.0.1:6881         CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:53133        127.0.0.1:21332        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:53136        127.0.0.1:21332        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:53137        127.0.0.1:6881         CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:53138        127.0.0.1:21332        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:53142        127.0.0.1:21332        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:53145        127.0.0.1:21332        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:53147        127.0.0.1:21332        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:53150        127.0.0.1:21332        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:53152        127.0.0.1:6881         CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:53153        127.0.0.1:21332        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:53156        127.0.0.1:6881         CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:53163        127.0.0.1:6881         CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:53167        127.0.0.1:6881         CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:53169        127.0.0.1:21332        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:53174        127.0.0.1:6881         CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:53192        127.0.0.1:21332        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:53195        127.0.0.1:21332        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:53202        127.0.0.1:21332        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:53203        127.0.0.1:6881         USTANOWIONO
  TCP       127.0.0.1:53206        127.0.0.1:21332        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:53209        127.0.0.1:21332        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:53212        127.0.0.1:21332        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:53215        127.0.0.1:21332        CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:53216        127.0.0.1:6881         CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       127.0.0.1:60429        127.0.0.1:60430        USTANOWIONO
  TCP       127.0.0.1:60430        127.0.0.1:60429        USTANOWIONO
  TCP       192.168.1.155:139      0.0.0.0:0              NASťUCHIWANIE
  TCP       192.168.1.155:2869     192.168.1.190:57113    OCZEKIWANIE_ZAMKN
  TCP       192.168.1.155:49371    209.49.122.50:5222     USTANOWIONO
  TCP       192.168.1.155:51777    5.42.176.248:3724      USTANOWIONO
  TCP       192.168.1.155:52017    198.252.206.149:443    USTANOWIONO
  TCP       192.168.1.155:52972    198.252.206.149:443    USTANOWIONO
  TCP       192.168.1.155:53058    64.74.103.73:12975     USTANOWIONO
  TCP       192.168.1.155:53071    80.239.186.21:80       CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       192.168.1.155:53072    80.239.186.21:80       CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       192.168.1.155:53077    80.239.186.21:80       CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       192.168.1.155:53078    80.239.186.21:80       CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       192.168.1.155:53083    213.241.88.208:80      USTANOWIONO
  TCP       192.168.1.155:53098    12.129.242.21:80       CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       192.168.1.155:53107    80.239.186.21:80       CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       192.168.1.155:53108    12.129.242.21:80       CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       192.168.1.155:53109    80.239.186.21:80       CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       192.168.1.155:53110    12.129.242.21:80       CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       192.168.1.155:53111    80.239.186.21:80       CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       192.168.1.155:53121    12.129.242.21:80       CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       192.168.1.155:53140    91.185.190.233:80      CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       192.168.1.155:53213    91.185.190.233:80      CZAS_OCZEKIWANIA
  TCP       192.168.1.155:54419    77.234.44.62:80        USTANOWIONO
  TCP       192.168.1.155:60431    80.239.208.193:1119    USTANOWIONO
  TCP       192.168.1.155:60669    195.12.234.52:80       OCZEKIWANIE_ZAMKN
  TCP       192.168.1.155:60675    213.248.127.130:1119   USTANOWIONO
  TCP       192.168.1.155:60700    5.42.177.25:3724       USTANOWIONO
  TCP       [::]:135               [::]:0                 NASťUCHIWANIE
  TCP       [::]:445               [::]:0                 NASťUCHIWANIE
  TCP       [::]:554               [::]:0                 NASťUCHIWANIE
  TCP       [::]:2869              [::]:0                 NASťUCHIWANIE
  TCP       [::]:5357              [::]:0                 NASťUCHIWANIE
  TCP       [::]:10243             [::]:0                 NASťUCHIWANIE
  TCP       [::]:49152             [::]:0                 NASťUCHIWANIE
  TCP       [::]:49153             [::]:0                 NASťUCHIWANIE
  TCP       [::]:49154             [::]:0                 NASťUCHIWANIE
  TCP       [::]:49159             [::]:0                 NASťUCHIWANIE
  TCP       [::]:49194             [::]:0                 NASťUCHIWANIE
  TCP       [::]:54535             [::]:0                 NASťUCHIWANIE
  TCP       [::]:64738             [::]:0                 NASťUCHIWANIE
  TCP       [::]:64738             [::]:0                 NASťUCHIWANIE
  TCP       [::1]:12025            [::]:0                 NASťUCHIWANIE
  TCP       [::1]:12110            [::]:0                 NASťUCHIWANIE
  TCP       [::1]:12119            [::]:0                 NASťUCHIWANIE
  TCP       [::1]:12143            [::]:0                 NASťUCHIWANIE
  TCP       [::1]:12465            [::]:0                 NASťUCHIWANIE
  TCP       [::1]:12563            [::]:0                 NASťUCHIWANIE
  TCP       [::1]:12993            [::]:0                 NASťUCHIWANIE
  TCP       [::1]:12995            [::]:0                 NASťUCHIWANIE
  TCP       [::1]:27275            [::]:0                 NASťUCHIWANIE
  TCP       [::1]:60378            [::1]:64738            USTANOWIONO
  TCP       [::1]:64738            [::1]:60378            USTANOWIONO
  UDP       0.0.0.0:500            *:*                    
  UDP       0.0.0.0:3702           *:*                    
  UDP       0.0.0.0:3702           *:*                    
  UDP       0.0.0.0:3702           *:*                    
  UDP       0.0.0.0:3702           *:*                    
  UDP       0.0.0.0:4020           *:*                    
  UDP       0.0.0.0:4021           *:*                    
  UDP       0.0.0.0:4500           *:*                    
  UDP       0.0.0.0:5004           *:*                    
  UDP       0.0.0.0:5005           *:*                    
  UDP       0.0.0.0:5060           *:*                    
  UDP       0.0.0.0:5355           *:*                    
  UDP       0.0.0.0:9987           *:*                    
  UDP       0.0.0.0:20041          *:*                    
  UDP       0.0.0.0:21328          *:*                    
  UDP       0.0.0.0:50516          *:*                    
  UDP       0.0.0.0:52579          *:*                    
  UDP       0.0.0.0:53545          *:*                    
  UDP       0.0.0.0:54968          *:*                    
  UDP       0.0.0.0:59046          *:*                    
  UDP       0.0.0.0:59048          *:*                    
  UDP       0.0.0.0:59050          *:*                    
  UDP       0.0.0.0:62829          *:*                    
  UDP       0.0.0.0:63846          *:*                    
  UDP       0.0.0.0:63848          *:*                    
  UDP       0.0.0.0:64302          *:*                    
  UDP       0.0.0.0:65155          *:*                    
  UDP       0.0.0.0:65275          *:*                    
  UDP       127.0.0.1:1900         *:*                    
  UDP       127.0.0.1:5065         *:*                    
  UDP       127.0.0.1:53159        *:*                    
  UDP       127.0.0.1:53160        *:*                    
  UDP       127.0.0.1:55001        *:*                    
  UDP       192.168.1.155:137      *:*                    
  UDP       192.168.1.155:138      *:*                    
  UDP       192.168.1.155:1900     *:*                    
  UDP       192.168.1.155:2177     *:*                    
  UDP       192.168.1.155:5353     *:*                    
  UDP       192.168.1.155:55000    *:*                    
  UDP       192.168.1.155:56179    *:*                    
  UDP       [::]:500               *:*                    
  UDP       [::]:3702              *:*                    
  UDP       [::]:3702              *:*                    
  UDP       [::]:3702              *:*                    
  UDP       [::]:3702              *:*                    
  UDP       [::]:4500              *:*                    
  UDP       [::]:5004              *:*                    
  UDP       [::]:5005              *:*                    
  UDP       [::]:5355              *:*                    
  UDP       [::]:59047             *:*                    
  UDP       [::]:59049             *:*                    
  UDP       [::]:59051             *:*                    
  UDP       [::]:62830             *:*                    
  UDP       [::]:63613             *:*                    
  UDP       [::]:64738             *:*                    
  UDP       [::1]:1900             *:*                    
  UDP       [::1]:5353             *:*                    
  UDP       [::1]:54999            *:*                    
  UDP       [fe80::e13d:df68:a9a1:e87f%13]:546  *:*                    
  UDP       [fe80::e13d:df68:a9a1:e87f%13]:1900  *:*                    
  UDP       [fe80::e13d:df68:a9a1:e87f%13]:2177  *:*                    
  UDP       [fe80::e13d:df68:a9a1:e87f%13]:54998  *:*
```

Comment: is the client connecting on the correct port?  DMZ have that port open to the outside?

Comment: Well, we tested port (default) so it should be correct. DMZ should got opened proper ports cuz it is possible to connect to teamspeak server on same host.